# Azure Dev Ops -Get all work item id with specific state

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am currently working with the Azure Dev Ops and have been asked to write a script that will remove the acceptance criteria and description from work items which have been on the board for 7 years.

This is my first time working with the ADO rest api, and am struggling understand the the WIQL part to write the query.

My logical process to resolve this task is,

1. Use the rest API to get all the work items by id that have their State = Done.
2. Use the list of ID's to make a patch request, and update the description and acceptance criteria.
3. Somehow make it run, and update the work items that are seven years old.

Atm, I am trying to get get the correct Query to actually pass into the the options of the API call, I am using Google App Script.

The query I have atm is

> "Select [System.Id] From WorkItems where [State] <> 'Done'"

I didn't quite understand the WIQL section of the documentation, but just wondering if anyone could help or has any experience.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you could install the [WIQL extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor) first.
Then you could create a query with your clauses, and then click the three dots edit query WIQL.
You will get the WIQL text.

After that, you could use the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query-by-wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP#get-results-of-a-flat-work-item-query.) to list the WIQL query.

[image: wiql]